# Final relay able to encrypt data to the client?

Tags: attacks, deanonymization, protocol

Have been reading the one cell is enough to break anonymity paper, and just have a question.

Once a circuit has been successfully created, can the final node of the circuit encrypt a piece of data and send it back through the circuit, or can it only do this when a TCP stream have been set up, and if so regrading the stream, could a extra packet be inserted into the stream?

Thanks guys

Comment: Looks quite similar to https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/5997/is-exit-node-able-to-modify-add-packets-to-a-stream -- I wonder if they should be merged?